# Liferay - how to retrieve properties of custom document type from webcontent velocity template

Tags: liferay, velocity

I am using custom document type for images in document and media folder.
My webcontent structure has a field that uses document and media for a image.
While creating the content i click document field and upload the image from my custom document type.

So far its good and it works. However we have some fields in custom document type I am trying to retrieve doesn't work. My question is how can I retrieve the document and media object in webcontent velosity template so that i can get access to the document type properties. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Below code will retrieve fileentry for you:

```
#set($docService = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLAppLocalService"))
#set($url = $httpUtil.decodeURL($document.getData(), true))
#set($parts = $stringUtil.split($url, "/"))
#set($group_id = $getterUtil.getLong($parts.get(2)))
#set($folder_id = $getterUtil.getLong($parts.get(3)))
#set($doc_name = $parts.get(4))
#set($fileEntry = $docService.getFileEntry($group_id, $folder_id, $doc_name))
```

You can look into `/ROOT/html/portlet/document_library/view_file_entry.jsp` file for retrieving custom document type fields and values.